# Encapsulation for ObservableBoolean in ViewModel class

Tags: android, encapsulation, android-viewmodel

In ViewModel we can apply `Encapsulation` for `MutableLiveData` as shown in [Android architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvvm-live-kotlin/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksViewModel.kt) :

```
private val _dataLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val dataLoading: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _dataLoading
```

As a result `dataLoading` can not be changed from Fragment or Activity since it is `LiveData` and not `MutableLiveData`

How about `ObservableBoolean` that we may use for `DataBinding` in ViewModel class for instance :

```
val isLoading = ObservableBoolean(false)
```

It can not be private since we use it in `DataBinding` :

```
<data>
        <variable
                name="vm"
                type="com.sample.android.ui.DetailViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:visibleGone="@{!vm.isLoading}">
```

So, how we can apply `Encapsulation` for `ObservableBoolean` as presented in Google sample?

Comment: how about using a setter in your view model  that updates the LiveData object ?

Comment: I meant `ObservableBoolean` not `LiveData`. Using `LiveData` is already follow encapsulation as I wrote in question.

Comment: same thing. Private field a getter and a setter. And from your xml you reference the getter

Comment: Please share it as answer in code. thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you could have

```
private val loading = ObservableBoolean(false)
```

and in your `vm`

```
fun isLoading() = loading
```

if you want to change the loading state from your fragment/activity you could expose a setter

```
   fun setLoading(value: Boolean) {
       loading.set(value)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, And do you think it is a better design following encapsulation?

Comment: it does make sense not to expose state directly. You could change internally something without the client not knowing it (unless you change getter and setter of course)

Comment: How is this correct when you can do isLoading().set(true) ?

Comment: It is the closest you can get using it. @toshkinl